# Android studio unable to create new project : IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android-studio

I have Java Version 8 Update 25, and Android Studio 0.8.6
I am trying to create a new project and it fails saying  :

```
12:20:00 PM IllegalArgumentException: Argument 0 for @NotNull parameter of com/intellij/openapi/vfs/VfsUtilCore.virtualToIoFile must not be null: Argument 0 for @NotNull parameter of com/intellij/openapi/vfs/VfsUtilCore.virtualToIoFile must not be null
```

Can someone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

Close you android Studio then delete **.AndroidStudio** setting folder 
**( in windows, C:\Users{YOUR_ACCOUNT}.AndroidStudio )**
and start your android studio again. It will reconfigure the settings and solves your problem.
 hope it helps..